# Python JSON count

Tags: python-3.x

I have a json file like this:

```json
{
  "lottery": [
    {
      "1": null,
      "2": null,
      "3": null,
      "4": null
    }
  ]
}
```

how can I count how many times `null` appears?

Comment: Please tell us more.  For instance, does the JSON follow a [schema](https://json-schema.org/) or are you not sure at all of the structure?

Comment: That's the whole json file, there's no more, so you can see the structure :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

lottery = '{ "lottery": [{ "1": null, "2": null, "3": null, "4": null }] }'
lotteryDict = json.loads(lottery)["lottery"][0]

count = 0
for value in lotteryDict.values():
  if value is None:
    count+=1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

As a one-liner, you can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) with `sum()`:

```
>>> import json
>>> lottery = '{ "lottery": [{ "1": null, "2": null, "3": null, "4": null }] }'
>>> sum(1 for i in json.loads(lottery)['lottery'][0].values() if i is None)
4
```